# Is $C = \{(x, y, z) ∈ R^3: x + y + z = 1, x^2 + y^2 + z =7/4\}.$ compact?

Tags: calculus, general-topology, multivariable-calculus

Is the following set compact? How can I show it? $C = \{(x, y, z) ∈ R^3: x + y + z = 1, x^2 + y^2 + z =7/4\}.$

Clearly it is closed as it contains its boundary, but I can not show that it is bounded..

Comment: What have you tried, and where did you get stuck? Please edit your question to include your efforts.

Comment: It's given by setting two continuous functions equal to constants, so it is closed. What set in the $xy$-plane does this region lie above? Is it a bounded set? Does this help?

Comment: Solve the second equation for $z$, substitute in the first equation.  Show that you get the equation of a circle.

Comment: Is showing that the set is $(x-1/2)^2+(y-1/2)^2=5/4$, by substituting $z=1-x-y$ in the first equation the only way to prove compactness?

Comment: That is NOT the set. That's the projection of the boundary of the set to the $xy$-plane. Note that a sphere is compact and a hyperboloid is not, so you have to work on boundedness somehow.

Comment: Ok, thank you. But showing that the projection of the boundary of the set to the xy plane is compact implies that the set $C = \{(x, y, z) ∈ R^3: x + y + z = 1, x^2 + y^2 + z =7/4\}.$ is compact. Is this correct?

Comment: No: the line $x=y=0$ is not compact, but its projection to the $xy$-plane is a single point. And if you knew the boundary of the original set, then you wouldn't need to project anywhere to determine whether it was compact.

Comment: So knowing that the projection is bounded, how do I show that the original set is  ounded as well?

Answer (score 2):

Substituting, we find that $x^2+y^2-x-y = (x-\frac{1}{2})^2 - \frac{1}{4} + (y-\frac{1}{2})^2 - \frac{1}{4} =  \frac{3}{4}$, ie $(x-\frac{1}{2})^2 + (y-\frac{1}{2})^2 = \frac{1}{4}$, so the projection of $C$ on the z-plane is a circle, which is bounded as $|x|\le K$, $|y|\le K$ for some constant $K$.

Now, going back to the first equation we have that $|z| = |1-x-y| \le |1| + |x| + |y| \le 1+2K$, so $z$ is bounded as well.

We conclude that $C$ is bounded, and since you already know how to show that it is closed, we conclude that it is compact.